# Accessing controls in embedded page in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I have a page that I am displaying in my main window, but I can't seem to access controls on the page from the main window's cs file.

This is the main window:

```
<Window 
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Frame Name="frame0" Source="SubPage.xaml" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

This is the page I'd like to embed:

```
<Page 
      d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300"
      Title="SubPage">

    <Grid>
        <Label x:Name="labelName" Content="Name:" />
        <TextBox x:Name="textName" Text="TextBox"/>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Here is how I've tried to access the sub-controls:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private XmlDocument xmlDoc;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        TextBox textName = (TextBox)frame0.Template.FindName("textName", frame0);
    }
}
```

Unfortunately `textName` is always `null`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `TextBox` is not part of the Frame's template. It is part of the Page's Content.

If you set the `x:FieldModifier` attribute of the `TextBox` in `SubPage.xaml` to `public` or `internal` or expose it through a property of the `SubPage.xaml.cs` class...:

```
<TextBox x:Name="textName" Text="TextBox" x:FieldModifier="public"/>
```

...you can get a reference to it by casting the `Content` property of the `Frame` to a `SubPage` once the page has been navigated to:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        frame0.Navigated += Frame0_Navigated;
    }

    private void Frame0_Navigated(object sender, System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        SubPage subPage = frame0.Content as SubPage;
        if (subPage != null)
        {
            TextBox textName = subPage.textName;
        }
        //remove the event handler
        frame0.Navigated -= Frame0_Navigated;
    }
}
```

Before this there is no `Page` nor `TextBox` because the instance of the `SubPage` hasn't yet been created.

Comment: `SubPage subPage = frame0.Content as SubPage` is the solution, thanks.